# Как достать файл из QNX?

Tags: qnx

Есть HW под управлением QNX
Сверху есть надстройка ANDROID
Есть локальный ПК (на Windows)

Андроид и ПК могут общаться через ADB. Можно перекидывать файлы и так далее.
Но у QNX совершенно другой пулл IP-адресов, чем у ПК и андроид. Подключение происходит с ПК к QNX через ком-порт и PuTTy.

Мы можем сохранить файл лога на QNX, используя простое перенаправление вывода, находясь в QNX-терминале:

```
slog2info > qnx.log
```

Но остаётся вопрос, как потом этот qnx.log доставить на локаьный ПК?

Есть ли какой-либо способ переправить файл лога с QNX на андроид? Или сразу на ПК?

Возможно, есть какая-либо возможность перенаправить вывод QNX консоли сразу на ПК, или перекинуть непосредственно файл лога с QNX на андроид или ПК?